h2o Dataframe Causes Function to Hang h2o.remove()
I have a data science project utilizing h2o where I setup a loop of heatmap visualizations for explain-ability and to measure overfitting. I want to be able to call the heatmap via a reusable function so I can return the heatmap to display alone or export a series of them to PDF. When I return the figure from the function it hangs. I've debugged by checking the time prior to return and the first statement after return and it takes around 200 seconds.
I spent a bunch of time trying to debug the timing but no matter what I did...it didn't return for 200 seconds. Inevitably, I figured out that there was some sort of garbage collection happening with the h2o dataframe when the function returned. I was able to add the line h2o.remove(shocked_hf) to the function to confirm this. This statement now took 200 seconds and the function returned fine. Here is a snippet of code that shows how the H2OFrame was created:
# create dataframe with simulated data to test model
shocked_df = pd.DataFrame(shocked_rows)
# this h2o frame is only 625 rows by 107 columns
shocked_hf = h2o.H2OFrame(shocked_df)
# this next statement takes around 200 seconds
h2o.remove(shocked_hf)

What is going on here? I'd like to call this function multiple times so there is really no reason to clean up this variable. Even if you do clean it up, there has to be a faster way. I've seen some thoughts of using manual garbage collection, however I think that will just introduce other issues. I think I may need to include the loop inside the function as a stopgap solution, but this just doesn't feel right.
